# Special use function - product of two lists

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I got a function:

```
template <typename Key, typename Info>
Sequence<Key,Info> produce( Sequence<Key,Info> &s1, int start1, int length1, Sequence<Key,Info> &s2, int start2, int length2, int limit)
```

where s1 and s2 are two sequences, start1 and start2- starting positions for both sequences, length1 and length2- lengths of offsets and limit- the length of the whole produced sequence (product of PRODUCE).

**Example**
s1=[1 2 3 4 5]

s2=[10 20 30 40 50]

s3= produce(s1, 2, 2, s2, 1, 3, 12)=[3 4 20 30 40 5 1 50 10 2]

*limit is 12 but we used all elements from both lists*

```
class Sequence
{
struct Node{
    Key key;
    Info info;
    Node *next;
};

Node *head = NULL;
```

When s1, s2 are empty or limit=0 , then it returns empty list:

```
if ((k == 0 && l == 0)|limit==0)
{
     return prod; // lays in a Sequence construction
}
```

Otherwise:

```
typename Sequence<Key,Info>::iterator q;
typename Sequence<Key,Info>::iterator r;

q = s1.begin();
q = q + start1;

r = s2.begin();
r = r + start2;
```

I got figured out the piece to move with those chunks through:

```
prod.insertFront(s1.get_key(q), s1.get_info(q));
if (s1.end(q))
{
q = s1.begin();
continue;
}
q = q + 1;
```

and

```
prod.insertFront(s2.get_key(r), s2.get_info(r));
if (s2.end(r))
{
r = s2.begin();
continue;
}
r = r + 1;
```

Now I wonder how to make those chunks together for the case when I have to take elements which are left and to make them connect when the iterator is in the end of the Sequence and has to go to the head, like in the example.

Comment: You have `(k == 0 && l == 0)|limit==0` as a condition. Do you really mean to use the *bitwise or* operator `|`? Or should it be the *logical or* operator `||`?

Comment: Besides that, please try to create a [mcve] to show us, instead of several code snippets that we don't know how they belong together.

Comment: Example is below the function short explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <typename Key, typename Info>
Sequence<Key,Info> produce( Sequence<Key,Info> &s1, int start1, int length1, Sequence<Key,Info> &s2, int start2, int length2, int limit)
{
Sequence<Key,Info> prod;
int k = s1.length();
int l = s2.length();
int m;

if ((k == 0 && l == 0)|limit==0)
{
cout<<"Test"<<endl;
 return prod;
}


typename Sequence<Key,Info>::iterator q;
typename Sequence<Key,Info>::iterator r;

 q = s1.begin();
 q = q + start1;

 r = s2.begin();
 r = r + start2;

if(length2!=0|| length1!=0 )
while (prod.length() < limit )
{


if(k==0)
{
 for (int j = 0; j < length2 && prod.length() < limit; j++)
 {
  prod.insertEnd(s2.get_key(r), s2.get_info(r));
  if (s2.end(r))
  {
   r = s2.begin();
   continue;
  }
 r = r + 1;
 }

}



if(l==0)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < length1 && prod.length() < limit; i++)
  {
   prod.insertEnd(s1.get_key(q), s1.get_info(q));
   if (s1.end(q))
  {
   q = s1.begin();
   continue;
  }
q = q + 1;
 }

}

//cout<<"zdjjdh"<<endl;
 if (k!= 0 && l!=0)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < length1 && prod.length() < limit; i++)
  {
   prod.insertEnd(s1.get_key(q), s1.get_info(q));
   if (s1.end(q))
  {
   q = s1.begin();
   continue;
  }
q = q + 1;
 }
 for (int j = 0; j < length2 && prod.length() < limit; j++)
 {
  prod.insertEnd(s2.get_key(r), s2.get_info(r));
  if (s2.end(r))
  {
   r = s2.begin();
   continue;
  }
 r = r + 1;
 }
}


}

return prod;
cout<<endl;

}
```